# as reference for controller usage in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<h1 ng-controller="mainController as mainCtrl">{{ms}}</h1>

.controller("mainController",function(){
this.ms = "hi";
});
```

Why are people using `as` in angularjs? What I usually do is just inject $scope and do `$scope.ms = 'something'`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to inject `$scope` if you do this

```
<h1 ng-controller="mainController as mainCtrl">{{mainCtrl.ms}}</h1>

app.controller("mainController", function() {
    this.ms = "hi";
});
```

Better explained [here](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/).

**EDIT**: It's mentioned in AngularJS Official Docs as well. See [ngController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController).

Comment: is this a new thing? if it's a preferred way why don't angular official site don't use it?